# How to pass string by reference in a swig produced C# function?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, swig

I have the following c function:

```
int GetB(const char* a, char *b);
```

I would like to produce the following C# function using swig:

```
int GetB(string a, out string b);
```

I tried the following in the swig interface file:

```
%include "typemaps.i" 
%apply signed char *OUTPUT {char *b}; 
int GetB(const char* a, char *OUTPUT);
```

but this produces:

```
int GetB(string a, out sbyte b)
```

If I use:

```
%apply char *OUTPUT {char *b};
```

I get:

```
"warning 453: Can't apply (char *OUTPUT). No typemaps are defined."
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: I'm guessing that `string` is not a valid type in C, which is why you're getting `out sbyte b` instead of `out string b`.

Comment: Yes, but maybe you could use a transformation of sbyte array to string somehow in the swig interface file.